# Rewrite inline javascript to external function - this reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm trying to rewrite some javascript code from an inline button onclick call to an regular javascript function.

I used the this reference in my code to remove a table column, which worked perfectly fine. Since I need to use the line of code on a few places I want it to be in a regular javascript function.

What I had:

```
<button type="button"  tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-secondary btn-tblrmv" onclick="if(!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass('notDeletable')){ $(this).closest('tr').remove(); }">
   <i class="mdi mdi-minus"></i>
</button>
```

as for the javasript function itself:

```
function removeTableRow(){
     if(!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass('notDeletable')){ 
          $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
     }
}
```

Could someone please explain, why this isn't working as intended?

Comment: `$(this)` is referenced if you call it from inside an element, otherwise you need to pass it to your custom function as a parameter `function removeTableRow(element){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This do not work because *this* is not referring to the current element. Try with:

HTML:

```
  <button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-secondary btn-tblrmv" onclick="removeTableRow(this)">
       <i class="mdi mdi-minus"></i>
    </button>
```

JS:

```
function removeTableRow (row) {
     if (!$(row).closest('tr').hasClass('notDeletable')) { 
          $(row).closest('tr').remove(); 
     }
}
```

Comment: ah, wow. thank you very much. I didn't know I cloud just reference like this! Will mark you as correct in a couple days as soon as stackoverflow let's me

Comment: No problem mate, glad I've helped :)